# App in Azure ASE needs to authenticate with NTML Web Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ntlm

`App` is running in Azure Service Environment (ASE).

ASMX web service `WS` is running in VM on `Domain`.

Pre-Azure/on-prem app uses `Domain\usr` and password for authentication.

How does one connect `App` to `WS` when `App` is in ASE, but `WS` is on Domain?

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about authentication, then take a look at Azure application Proxy. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy
this will likely do what you want. 
Here's a bit more of a tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-secure-api-access

Probably you'd have to publish the on-prem app in the app proxy. then access it using the web app on ase as if it were a native client in the example?

never tried it. so if someone has a better suggestion feel free to correct me.

Regards,